# Landing screen in Google Analytics refers to mobile web pages or apps?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics

I'm pretty new to GA. And I'm stumbling over the term "landing screen".

It is defined as "**the name of the first viewed screen**." I'm aware this is referring to mobile. But say, if I'm viewing the New York Times from safari vs the NYT app, does the "landing screen" track my safari page view or the one in app?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on implementation but not how you view the page. You can set up only app or only web Analytics. If you are implementing​ app analytics you cannot see "landing pages" in your reports